# Leiningen: Tried to use insecure HTTP repository without TLS

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to work through the [Enlive tutorial](https://github.com/swannodette/enlive-tutorial/).

When I try `lein deps` or `lein run` within the cloned repo, I run into this issue:

> Tried to use insecure HTTP repository without TLS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recent versions of Leiningen have disabled insecure dependency downloads. From the [FAQ](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md):

> Q: I got `Tried to use insecure HTTP repository without TLS`, what is that about?
>
> A: This means your project was configured to download dependencies from a repository that does not use TLS encryption. This is very insecure and exposes you to trivially-executed man-in-the-middle attacks. In the rare event that you don't care about the security of the machines running your project or can ensure that the only http traffic is going out over a trusted network, you can re-enable support for unsafe repositories by putting this in your `project.clj` file:

```
;; never do this
(require 'cemerick.pomegranate.aether)
(cemerick.pomegranate.aether/register-wagon-factory!
 "http" #(org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon.))
```

> It's also possible you have a dependency which includes a reference to an insecure repository for retrieving its own dependencies. If this happens it is strongly recommended to add an `:exclusion` and report a bug with the dependency which does this.

**Overriding insecure HTTP repository URLs in `project.clj`:**

I'm able to clone `enlive-tutorial` and do `lein deps` successfully if I override the following repository URLs in `enlive-tutorial/project.clj`, simply changing the protocol to HTTPS:

```
:mirrors {"clojure" {:url "https://build.clojure.org/releases/"}
          "clojure-snapshots" {:url "https://build.clojure.org/snapshots/"}}
```

It appears [Moustache](https://github.com/cgrand/moustache/blob/master/pom.xml) is the transitive dependency that's attempting to pull its dependencies via HTTP.